# Reader with highlight tool

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-reader

I want a pdf reader just like adobe reader with highlight tool and full screen mode. Also with change background ,text color feature?

Comment: Adobe does actually have an official, (albeit *very* old) version of Acrobat for Linux

Comment: Is the old version  Adobe 9.0?

Comment: Yes. Although you may have success running the Windows version in WINE

Answer (score 1):

1. The default Document Viewer application (evince) in Ubuntu has true full screen mode. ✅ 
   ( *View* -> *Presentation* )
2. Document Viewer also has a highlight tool. ✅

   In Ubuntu 16.04 and later, the icon for adding an annotation or highlighting looks like a spiral bound notepad. Clicking this icon reveals two other icons in the toolbar below it, one of which is the highlighting icon. The highlighting icon looks like a piece of paper with three black blocks on it, marked by a yellow diagonal arrow in the below screenshot.

   [image: IMG:]

   Click on the spot in the document window you would like to add the highlight to, and drag the mouse to highlight it.

   Select the *File* -> *Save a Copy* button to save the highlighting.
3. Changing text and background colors is not supported in Document Viewer except for *View* -> *Inverted Colors*.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/). It's not open source but its free.

### Main Features:

- **Highlighting**: 10 color highlighting options available with opacity adjustment.
- **Squiggly**: 10 color squiggly underlining options with opacity adjustments.
- **Basic Underlining**: 10 color basic underlining options with opacity adjustments.
- **Strikeout**: 10 color strikeout options with opacity adjustments.
- **Replace Text**
- **Insert Text**
- **Display Modes**: 6 color display modes available(including night mode).
- **Connect Pdf**: Take your pdf to cloud and share with collaborators and they can comment and highlight as well.

**Other Features**: Typewriter, textbox, callout, note, Shape, Pencil, Eraser, Area Highlight.

[image: Foxit Reader]

**Note**: All these features are specific for Linux Version of the app (which is simply awesome). The Windows version may have some differences.